# Java ServerSocket bound but not listening

Tags: java, windows, java-8, serversocket, netstat

I have the following code for a keepalive serversocket, jdk 1.8, windows7 :

```
  serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
  serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
  serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port)); // <-- port is 19876
  System.out.println("Server bound on " + port + " " + serverSocket);
```

The problem is sometimes when I run this, it shows up listening in netstat, but sometimes it doesn't. Since there is no exception I'd expect it to be actually bound, but it's random.

Correct operation, netstat just after the println:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:19876          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7944
  TCP    [::]:19876             [::]:0                 LISTENING       7944
```

Netstat just after the println:

```
C:\Users\tmplr>netstat -ano | find "198"

C:\Users\tmplr>netstat -ano | find "198"
```

In both cases there is no exception and the println produces the same :

```
Server bound on 19876 ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=19876]
```

Any idea what's wrong here or how could I debug the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the accept method for it to listen :

```
boolean isStopped = false;
while(!isStopped){
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

    //do something with clientSocket
}
```

Comment: Then why is it listening in the first case without calling accept ? In my understanding `listen` is already included in calling `bind`.